# how to solve the recursion problem when specifying type hints for classes from different files

Tags: python, recursion, type-hinting, python-dataclasses

how to solve the recursion problem when specifying type hints for classes from different files

**models1.py**

```
from models2 import Second
@dataclass
class First:
    attribute: Second
```

**models2.py**

```
from models1 import First
@dataclass
class Second:
    attribute: First
```

In real code, I wanted to split `SentInvoice` and `User` models into different files.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = fields.BigIntField(index=True, unique=True)
    username = fields.CharField(32, unique=True, index=True, null=True)
    first_name = fields.CharField(255, null=True)
    last_name = fields.CharField(255, null=True)
    language = fields.CharField(32, default="ru")
    balance: Balance = fields.OneToOneField("models.Balance", on_delete=fields.CASCADE)
    sent_invoice: fields.OneToOneNullableRelation["SentInvoice"] # here
    registered_user: RegisteredUser

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls: Type[MODEL], **kwargs: Any):
        return await super().create(**kwargs, balance=await Balance.create())


class SentInvoice(models.Model):
    amount = fields.DecimalField(17, 7)
    shop_id = fields.CharField(50)
    order_id = fields.CharField(10, null=True)
    email = fields.CharField(20, null=True)
    currency = fields.CharField(5, default="RUB", description="USD, RUB, EUR, GBP")
    user: fields.ForeignKeyRelation[User] = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", on_delete=fields.CASCADE)  # here
    created_invoice: fields.OneToOneNullableRelation[CreatedInvoice]

    async def send(self) -> CreatedInvoice:
        cryptocloud = config.payment.cryptocloud
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers={"Authorization": f"Token {cryptocloud.api_key}"}) as session:
            async with session.post(cryptocloud.create_url, data=dict(self)) as res:
                created_invoice = await CreatedInvoice.create(**await res.json(), sent_invoice=self)
                return created_invoice
```

Comment: won't these types use infinite memory? Moreover, how would you even make instances?

Comment: re type hints, you probably want to quote one of them e.g. `"First"` - i don't think forward annotations would work. That said, I don't know if that's possible with them in different modules

Comment: that is, to use quoted names I think the names still need to be in scope somewhere in the file. For that, you need the imports, which are circular

Comment: a mutually recursive type wil need to be defined in the same file. you should also provide a concrete example to demonstrate how it will be used. this goes a long way in helping you understand the implications of what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two techniques that are specific to type hinting in python, 1) [forward references](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/), and 2) importing types within a [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) guard (check e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61545580/how-does-mypy-use-typing-type-checking-to-resolve-the-circular-import-annotation) for a longer explanation of its implications). The first one allows you to reference a type that is not know to the interpreter at runtime, and the latter resolves types in a "type checking context".

Long story short:

**models1.py**

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from models2 import Second

@dataclass
class First:
    attribute: "Second"
```

**models2.py**

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from models1 import First

@dataclass
class Second:
    attribute: "First"
```

Executing the files with `python3.8` or higher should work without any issues<sup>[1]</sup>, and can work in `python3.7` as well [with a `__futures__` import](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7). Running `mypy` on the files should work without any issues, too:

```sh
$ mypy models1.py models2.py
Success: no issues found in 2 source files
```

---

<sup>[1] <sub>As comments have pointed out, creating actual instances of your `First`/`Second` classes that would also pass a type check is impossible, but I assume that this is a toy example and your real code has, for example, one of the attribues as `Optional`.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need. You are right, I have given this only as an example. In real code, I wanted to split several types of models into different files.