# Python type hinting for sake of VSCODE autocomplete causes circular imports,

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I need type hints for the sake of autocomplete in VSCODE. I have following:

```
# a.py

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = B(self)
```

```
# b.py

from a import A
# I NEED TO IMPORT A HERE SO I CAN REFER TO A IN TYPE HINT

class B:
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        self.A = a
```

This causes circular import. I have read, that it is allowed to type hint in between single quotation marks, but this removes the purpose for why I need it. It is VSCODE autocomplete. Once A is in quotation marks, VSCODE does not know what it is. I have read about stub files, but these wont work for me, because I would have to edit these files every time I change A class and I plan to have it a large class.

Comment: This might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61545580/how-does-mypy-use-typing-type-checking-to-resolve-the-circular-import-annotation

Comment: I have attempted your described solution already and I received an error: NameError: name 'A' is not defined, and I am stuck again

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to do this. Logically it should not work, because you need the one to create the other, but the other is needed to create the one in the first place... Maybe you could explain a bit more what your specific use case is...?

Comment: @Jon_Kle read the question again, then you will understand why do I need it.

Comment: If you use `def __init__(self, a: "A"):`  this works with mypy. If you're not sure stil, I can post a full solution

Comment: @Jokubas11 Oh, yeah missread it. Tried to implement it with the type checking approach. It works for me on plain Python3.11

Answer (score 1):

I think [TYPE_CHECKING](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) will solve the problem of your circular import.

Try import as in the following code.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from a import A
```

The following article may also be helpful for your understanding.
[Python type hinting without cyclic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports)

Comment: I was already aware of this solution, but all I get is NameError: name 'A' is not defined, and I am stuck again

Comment: Add `from __future__ import annotations`to the first line of the file and run it. This will probably solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried this with what Josmoor98 suggested in the comments of your question, defining A in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following files.

`a.py`

```py
from b import B

class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.b = B(self)
```

`b.py`

```py
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from a import A
    
class B:
    def __init__(self, a: "A"):
        self.a = a
        
# actual usage
def foo() -> None:
    B(1)
```

mypy will return `b.py:11: error: Argument 1 to "B" has incompatible type "int"; expected "A"  [arg-type]`

Depending on the linter you use, you may also get this information in your IDE. For me I get a listing error

```
Argument of type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to parameter "a" of type "A" in function "__init__" "Literal[1]" is incompatible with "A"Pylance
```